# use form under another form with seprate button

Tags: angularjs

I want use a form under another form in angularjs. First form (`form1`) is a `form-wizard`. I want use another form in `form1` and then goto another step of form-wizard. I want add some data in `form2` and push data in a list and then by form 1, goto another step. I have below code:

```
<form class="tab-pane" id="second-1" name="second-1Form" rc-submit rc-step>
  <form ng-submit="form2()">
    <div class="form-group">
      ...
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      ...
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <button>Submit</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</form>
<div class="form-group">
     <div class="pull-right">
       <a class="btn btn-default" ng-click="rc.sampleWizard.backward()"ng-show="rc.sampleWizard.currentIndex > rc.sampleWizard.firstIndex">Back</a>
       <a class="btn btn-primary" data-loading-text="Please Wait..." ng-click="rc.sampleWizard.forward()"ng-show="rc.sampleWizard.currentIndex < rc.sampleWizard.navigationLength">Continue</a>
       <a class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="rc.sampleWizard.forward()"ng-show="rc.sampleWizard.currentIndex == rc.sampleWizard.navigationLength">Complete</a>
     </div>
</div>
```

and in controller:

```
    $scope.addBolouk = function(){
        $scope.BoloukRadif.push($scope.formdata);
    };
```

but when I complete `form2` and click on `submit`, data don't add to list and `submit` of form-wizard is work and page is goto next form-wizrd.

I want add data to list by using first form and then goto next form-wizard. How can I seprate button of `form2` from button of `form-wizard`? How can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can't have a form inside a form, but you can use the [ng-form](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngForm) directive,

```
<form class="tab-pane" id="second-1" name="second-1Form" rc-submit rc-step>
  <ng-form>
    <div class="form-group">
      ...
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      ...
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <button ng-click="form2()">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </ng-form>
</form>
<div class="form-group">
     <div class="pull-right">
       <a class="btn btn-default" ng-click="rc.sampleWizard.backward()"ng-show="rc.sampleWizard.currentIndex > rc.sampleWizard.firstIndex">Back</a>
       <a class="btn btn-primary" data-loading-text="Please Wait..." ng-click="rc.sampleWizard.forward()"ng-show="rc.sampleWizard.currentIndex < rc.sampleWizard.navigationLength">Continue</a>
       <a class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="rc.sampleWizard.forward()"ng-show="rc.sampleWizard.currentIndex == rc.sampleWizard.navigationLength">Complete</a>
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I use this guide, but again when I click on `Submit`, button of first form is work and data don't push to list and page is goto next form-wizard.